# SSD upgrade of HP ProBook 4530s

Tags: laptop, ssd

I need to upgrade HP ProBook 4530s disk, what would you suggest, considering following requirements for the SSD:

- at least 200 GB
- max read & write above or around 500 MB/s
- around 100$, lower is better ;)

The current specs for HP ProBook 4530s are:

- 4GB Ram
- i3-2310M (2*2.1 + Multi Threading)
- 320 GB HDD 7200 rpm
- 15.6 display

I was thinking Samsung EVO 850 250 GB or ADATA SP550 240 GB. What dou you suggest?

Comment: Funfact: You should get 5 years warranty on that SSD if you don't write more than 20GB per day average of 5 years (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started using and recommending the [Sandisk Ultra II](http://pcpartpicker.com/search/?cc=us&q=sandisk+ultra+ii) drives for any relatively weak machines which do not do big continuous writing tasks.
It fits your criteria and is quite good (until you fill up the SLC cache - 10GB for the 240GB model).

Answer (score 1):

Go with the [Samsung EVO 850](https://goo.gl/zkTBQh) or the [Crucial MX300 275GB](https://goo.gl/Rol1I1).  I have used them in everything from Dell Latitudes, HP Desktops (I forget the model) to MacBook Pros and even my own personal iMac.

Personally, I wouldn't go with a SSD from a company that's not known to make quality memory modules (because that's technically what an SSD is). I'm not saying any of the off brands are "bad," it's just there is a "piece of mind" factor when it comes to my data and I would prefer to know a reputable brand well known for what they do.  It's as the old saying goes "You never get fired for buying IBM."

If you are upgrading your laptop and want more speed, I would also recommend [upgrading your RAM to 8GB](https://goo.gl/WPeDnS); [that the max for your machine.](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ProBook-4500-Notebook-PC-series/5060880/model/5060882/document/c02793462)

[image]